# Having a Drones.SE Hot Network Question feed in chat

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat

Recently, we have had a few questions that have got some heat:

- [Report a lost drone in the UK?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/report-a-lost-drone-in-the-uk)
- [Spray painting a drone, what to look out for?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/1006/spray-painting-a-drone-what-to-look-out-for)
- [What is a good alternative to carbon fibre for a quadcopter frame?](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/877/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-carbon-fibre-for-a-quadcopter-frame)

We could have a feed posted in a separate room of such questions (to not clog up the main chat), it allows us to monitor these questions for high-quality and is generally interesting to see.

What does everyone think?

If everyone agrees, I could set it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feed has now been created, check it out here:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107719/hot-network-questions-feed